# ${out.classes.dir} does not exist while using proguard and ANT

Tags: android, android-build

Hi i m using the following link
[here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29) but i am stuck getting this error..I spent a few hours and found that it can be set manually in local.properties or project.properties but i dont know how.
..Can i get a help???? I m able to build a release build otherwise but adding add-proguard-release.xml shows the error

Here is the detailed message

BUILD FAILED
D:\MyProject\add-proguard-release.xml:14: D:\MyProject\${out.classes.dir} does not exist.

Comment: That is a very old link for SDK 7, Have you checked out the proguard docs on the Android Dev site? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: @Ian Warwick yeah have checked that..but since than many things have changed in android and i m using the most updated SDK,ADT and Revision...It was the best way for current versions..As people came up with issues with the old one

Comment: The official documentation I linked is up-to-date, and that link provides the details you require to setup proguard for your build, if you are going to follow the guide that is for SDK 7 then it no longer works that way